# Trouble Adding a new field to a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a new field "UserInput" to my UserProfile model. First I added the field to my UserProfile table using:

```
ALTER TABLE [Database].[dbo].[UserProfile]
ADD UserInput nvarchar(max) NULL
```

Everything seems to work fine. I then added it to my model which produced the following:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FID { get; set; }
    public string UserInput { get; set; }
}
```

But then when I try to add it to my View, it gives me a red squiggly line, with the error:

```
 Error  1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FTv2.Models.UserProfile>' does not contain a definition for 'UserInput' and no extension method 'UserInput' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FTv2.Models.UserProfile>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Did I miss something? I was able to add a field this way previously, perhaps someone can tell me what I missed this time? Also I tried running the code and got an error when trying to access that page, which was the following:

```
Line 14:         <legend>Edit</legend>
Line 15:         <div class="editor-label">
Line 16:             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserInput)
Line 17:         </div>
Line 18:         <div class="editor-field">
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

edit: looks like the problem is with the fact that I am trying to edit the field from that view because if I only try to access item.UserInput it returns it fine. Here is where the code is not working:

```
@model IEnumerable<FTv2.Models.UserProfile>

using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserInput)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserInput)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserInput)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    }
```

But it works fine for the lower section:

```
@{ foreach (var item in Model) {
    <p>User Input: @item.UserInputTwo</p>
}}
```

Comment: I see no `UserInput` in your `UserProfile` model, only `UserInputTwo`

Comment: Your model is naming UserInput as UserInputTwo. I would think that the model would need it to be called UserInput. Also, being able to see the rest of "Error 1" may be helpful.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo in this post, it has been fixed.

Comment: Do you have any caps issues -- are you sure the model compiled without errors?

Comment: I did try a clean rebuild, same issue, though I messed around and found some more info. I have edited to include it if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are passing IEnumerable model.
In this case you should enumerate through all you model items and pass them into HtmlHelper methods.
And in this case I recommend you to pass List in your view like this:

```
@model List<FTv2.Models.UserProfile>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].UserInput)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].UserInput)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].UserInput)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem is that you aren't actually reading your error.

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FTv2.Models.UserProfile>' does 
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 not contain a definition for 'UserInput'
```

Your view has model of type IEnumerable, and IEnumerable does not have anything called UserInput in it.  Your UserProfile has UserInput.

Either you are passing the wrong model type to the view, or you need to iterate over the elements of the IEnumerable to get at the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The bit that works is because you're using `foreach` over your IEnumerable model. The bit that doesn't work is because you're not looping through your IEnumerable collection. IEnumerable doesn't have a `UserInput` property.

Try changing your model declaration.

```
@model FTv2.Models.UserProfile
```